# Android Volley JsonObjectRequest with multiple parameters

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm currently working on an android app and I need your help.

When I try to Use `JsonObjectRequest` supported by Volley, I get an error:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

This are my two relevant code snippets:

**Receiver.java**

```
public void sendNewInfo(String url, HashMap<String , String> params) {
    JsonObjectRequest newInfoRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params) , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //doing some fancy stuff here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(newInfoFragment.getActivity(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(newInfoRequest);
}
```

**NewInfoFragment.java**

```
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendeInfo);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.newInfoTitle);
            EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.newInfoText);

            HashMap<String , String> params = new HashMap<String , String>();
            params.put("appkey", "123");
            params.put("autor", ((NewInfo) getActivity()).getBenutzername());
            params.put("titel", title.getText().toString());
            params.put("text", text.getText().toString());

            Receiver receiver = new Receiver(infofragment);
            receiver.sendNewInfo("myurlstringhere", params);
        }
    });
}
```

Does somebody have a good solution or any idea how I can solve this?
The `params` are sent into the `Receiver` and he cannot resolve them into a `JsonObject` but I don't know how to do this.

**EDIT**
For all of you, who do have the same error, please recheck your JSON you get as response. If its not valid, Volley throws this exception!

Comment: What is the response you are getting? could you try using `AdvancedRestClient` or atleast please share the RestAPI URL you are using

Comment: @Mithun the response I get is: Value 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
The RestAPI is use is coded by myself. When I access it from another place (Ajax call / php / ...) it works!

Comment: Your `request` and `response` both ideally should be in JSON format otherwise, `Volley` won't be able to parse `response` and hence it throws `ParseException`. Without RestAPI its very hard to pinpoint the issue, as there could be problem in your `request` structure as well `response` also.

Comment: @Mithun In my opinion, both is JSON. I am creating a JSONObject and getting a JSONObject as response from my webservice. The data my webservice expects is a normal POST request with 4 variables, am I right that volley normally should do this? :/

Comment: I didn't see your updated code earlier... Your request seems to be fine! You are creating `Map` and sending it wrapped in a `JSONObject`... But thing is **Value 1** is basically a `String` and not a `JSON`! But question is, if you use `AdvancedRestClient` what value are you getting? If it is a `JSON` response there, then definitely There is some issue how we are sending our request and if not `Volley` has to be looked into for better debugging... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196601/volley-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject/30197539#30197539 if it gives some more info

Comment: See this screenshot: http://imgur.com/l4N3vC7 It works fine! "1" is the expected response...

Comment: I am at office now... can we continue may be after 2 hours from now? But **"1"** is definitely a valid json... Try validating *"1"* in http://jsonlint.com/ and you can see it

Comment: Thanks man, I got it. The problem was an unvalid JSON from my Webservice :/ Didnt expect volley to be so strict. Thanks @Mithun

Comment: Check this answer [Volley JsonObjectRequest Post request not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945676/3512164)